# Determine whether $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2-6y^2}{|x|+3|y|}$ exists or not

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Trying paths $y=mx$ and $x=0$ yields $0$, so trying $0$ as a candidate for this limit.

$$  \lim \limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \left |\frac{x^2-6y^2}{|x|+3|y|} -0 \right |$$

Observe:

$$\left |\frac{x^2-6y^2}{|x|+3|y|} \right| < \frac{|x^2+6y^2|}{|x|+3|y|} < \frac{|x^2|+5|xy|+6|y^2|}{|x|+3|y|}= \frac{(|x|+2|y|)(|x|+3|y|)}{|x|+3|y|}=|x|+2|y| $$

Using this as a squeeze function, it clearly $\to 0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

Hence by theorem,
$$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2-6y^2}{|x|+3|y|} =0$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Which norm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

since $$\frac {1}{|x|+3|y|}\le \frac {1}{|x|} $$
and
$$\frac {1}{|x|+3|y|}\le \frac {1}{3|y|} ,$$
we have

$$\frac {-6y^2}{3|y|}\le f (x,y)\le \frac {x^2}{|x|} $$

now squeeze.